# Improve Postgres performance

Tags: postgresql, performance, configuration, aggregation

I am new to Postgres and sure I’m doing something wrong.
So I just wondered if anybody had experienced something similar to my experiences below or could point me in the right direction to improve Postgres performance.

My initial goal was to speed up the analytical processing of my Datamarts in various Dashboards by moving from MS SQL Server to Postgres.
To get a sample query to compare speeds I ran query profiler on MS SQL Server whilst referencing a BI dashboard, which produced something similar to this (I know there are redundant columns in the sub query):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) 
FROM    (
        SELECT 
            BM.Key_Date, BM.[Actual Date], BM.[Month]
            ,BM.[Month Number], BM.[Month Year], BM.[No of Working Days]
            ,SDI.Key_Delivery, SDI.[Order Number], SDI.[Quantity SKU]
            ,SDI.[Quantity Sales Unit], SDI.[FactSales - GBP], SDI.[NNSA Capsules]
            ,SFI.[Ship-to], SFI.[Sold-to], SFI.[Sales Force Type], SFI.Region
            ,SFI.[Top Level Account], SFI.[Customer Organisation]
            ,EX.Rate
            ,PDI.[Product Description], PDI.[Product Type Group], PDI.[Product Type],
             PDI.[Main Product Categories], PDI.Section, PDI.Family
        FROM Fact.SalesDataInvoiced                     AS SDI
            JOIN Dimension.SalesforceInvoiced           AS SFI
                ON SDI.[Key_Ship-to]=SFI.[Key_Ship-to]
            JOIN Dimension.BillingMonth                 AS BM
                ON SDI.[Key_Billing Month]=BM.Key_Date
            JOIN Dimension.ProductDataInvoiced          AS PDI
                ON SDI.[Key_Product Code]=PDI.[Key_Product Code]
            CROSS JOIN Dimension.Exchange               AS EX
        WHERE BM.[Actual Date] BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20211001'
    ) AS a 
GROUP BY [Product Type], [Product Type Group],[Main Product Categories]
```

I then installed Postgres 14 (on Centos 8)  and MS SQL Server Developer 2017 (on windows 10) on separate identical laptops and created a Database and tables from the same csv data files to enable the replication of the above query.

Running a Postgres query with indexing performs massively slower than MS SQL without indexing.
Adding indexes to MS SQL produces results almost instantly.

Because of the difference in processing time I even installed Citus with Postgres14 and created Fact.SalesDataInvoiced as a columnar table (This made the processing time worse).
I have played about with memory settings in postgresql.conf but nothing seems to enable speeds comparable to MSSQL.

Explain Analyze shows that despite the indexes it always runs a sequential scan of all tables. Forcing indexed scans doesn't make any difference to processing time.

Would I be right in thinking Postgres would perform significantly better using a cluster and partitioning? Even if this is the case surely a simple query like the one I'm trying to run on a stand alone machine should be faster?

**TABLE DETAILS**

**Dimension.BillingMonth**
Records 120,
Primary Key is KeyDate,
Clustered Unique Index on KeyDate

**Dimension.Exchange**
Records 1

**Dimension.ProductDataInvoiced**
Records 275563,
Primary Key is KeyProduct,
Clustered Unique Index on KeyProduct

**Dimension.SalesforceInvoiced**
Records 377414,
Primary Key is KeyShipTo,
Clustered Unique Index on KeyShipTo

**Fact.SalesDataInvoiced**
Records 43807943,
Non-Clustered Unique Index on KeyShipTo, KeyProduct, KeyBillingMonth

Any help would be appreciated as previously mentioned I'm sure I must be missing something obvious.

Many thanks in advance.

David

---

Thank you for the responses. I have placed additional info below.

Forgot to add my postgres performance woes were after i'd carried out a Full Vacuum and Reindex. I performed these maintenance tasks after I had imported the data and created my indexes.

**Output after querying pg_indexes**

| tablename | indexname | indexdef |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BillingMonth | BillingMonth_pkey | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX BillingMonth_pkey ON public.BillingMonth USING btree (KeyDate) |
| ProductDataInvoiced | ProductDataInvoiced_pkey | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ProductDataInvoiced_pkey ON public.ProductDataInvoiced USING btree (KeyProductCode) |
| SalesforceInvoiced | SalesforceInvoiced_pkey | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SalesforceInvoiced_pkey ON public.SalesforceInvoiced USING btree (KeyShipTo) |
| SalesDataInvoiced | CI_SalesData | CREATE INDEX CI_SalesData ON public.SalesDataInvoiced USING btree (KeyShipTo, KeyProductCode, KeyBillingMonth) |

**Output After running EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)**

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=1435439.30..1435565.71 rows=480 width=53) (actual time=25960.468..25973.326 rows=31 loops=1)
   Group Key: pdi."ProductType", pdi."ProductTypeGroup", pdi."MainProductCategories"
   Buffers: shared hit=71246 read=859119
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1435439.30..1435551.31 rows=960 width=53) (actual time=25960.458..25973.282 rows=89 loops=1)
     Workers Planned: 2
     Workers Launched: 2
     Buffers: shared hit=71246 read=859119
     ->  Sort  (cost=1434439.28..1434440.48 rows=480 width=53) (actual time=25956.982..25956.989 rows=30 loops=3)
           Sort Key: pdi."ProductType", pdi."ProductTypeGroup", pdi."MainProductCategories"
           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 28kB
           Buffers: shared hit=71246 read=859119
           Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB
           Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB
           ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=1434413.10..1434417.90 rows=480 width=53) (actual time=25956.878..25956.895 rows=30 loops=3)
                 Group Key: pdi."ProductType", pdi."ProductTypeGroup", pdi."MainProductCategories"
                 Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 49kB
                 Buffers: shared hit=71230 read=859119
                 Worker 0:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 49kB
                 Worker 1:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 49kB
                 ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=62124.74..1327935.46 rows=10647764 width=45) (actual time=285.864..19240.004 rows=14602648 loops=3)
                       Hash Cond: (sdi."KeyShipTo" = sfi."KeyShipTo")
                       Buffers: shared hit=71230 read=859119
                       ->  Hash Join  (cost=19648.48..1257508.51 rows=10647764 width=49) (actual time=204.794..12862.063 rows=14602648 loops=3)
                             Hash Cond: (sdi."KeyProductCode" = pdi."KeyProductCode")
                             Buffers: shared hit=32264 read=859119
                             ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.67..1091456.95 rows=10647764 width=8) (actual time=0.143..7076.104 rows=14602648 loops=3)
                                   Hash Cond: (sdi."KeyBillingMonth" = bm."KeyDate")
                                   Buffers: shared hit=197 read=859119
                                   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on "SalesData_Invoiced" sdi  (cost=0.00..1041846.10 rows=18253310 width=12) (actual 
time=0.071..2585.596 rows=14602648 loops=3)
                                         Buffers: shared hit=194 read=859119
                                   ->  Hash  (cost=2.80..2.80 rows=70 width=4) (actual time=0.049..0.050 rows=70 loops=3)
                                   Hash Cond: (sdi."KeyBillingMonth" = bm."KeyDate")
                                   Buffers: shared hit=197 read=859119
                                   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on "SalesData_Invoiced" sdi  (cost=0.00..1041846.10 rows=18253310 width=12) (actual 
time=0.071..2585.596 rows=14602648 loops=3)
                                         Buffers: shared hit=194 read=859119
                                   ->  Hash  (cost=2.80..2.80 rows=70 width=4) (actual time=0.049..0.050 rows=70 loops=3)
                                         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
                                         Buffers: shared hit=3
                                         ->  Seq Scan on "BillingMonth" bm  (cost=0.00..2.80 rows=70 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.028 
rows=70 loops=3)
                                               Filter: (("ActualDate" >= '2016-01-01'::date) AND ("ActualDate" <= '2021-10-01'::date))
                                               Rows Removed by Filter: 50
                                               Buffers: shared hit=3
                             ->  Hash  (cost=16200.27..16200.27 rows=275563 width=49) (actual time=203.237..203.238 rows=275563 loops=3)
                                   Buckets: 524288  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 26832kB
                                   Buffers: shared hit=32067
                                   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..16200.27 rows=275563 width=49) (actual time=0.034..104.143 rows=275563 loops=3)
                                         Buffers: shared hit=32067
                                         ->  Seq Scan on "Exchange" ex  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=
1 loops=3)
                                               Buffers: shared hit=3
                                         ->  Seq Scan on "ProductData_Invoiced" pdi  (cost=0.00..13443.63 rows=275563 width=49) (actual 
time=0.007..48.176 rows=275563 loops=3)
                                               Buffers: shared hit=32064
                       ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=40510.56..40510.56 rows=157256 width=4) (actual time=79.536..79.536 rows=125805 loops=3)
                             Buckets: 524288  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 18912kB
                             Buffers: shared hit=38938
                             ->  Parallel Seq Scan on "Salesforce_Invoiced" sfi  (cost=0.00..40510.56 rows=157256 width=4) (actual time=
0.011..42.968 rows=125805 loops=3)
                                   Buffers: shared hit=38938
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=426
 Planning Time: 1.936 ms
 Execution Time: 25973.709 ms
(55 rows)
```

Comment: Did you run `VACUUM ANALYZE` before running your queries (after the first data import or after creating a new index)? What are your PostgreSQL indexes?

Comment: 1) Primary Keys 1a) Natural keys 2) foreign keys 2a) supporting indexes for FKs 3) maybe some additional indexes for specific queries 4) server configuration constants.

Comment: Examine the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I have now added additional information to my post

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remember to run `VACUUM ANALYZE` after rebuilding indexes, or sometimes after importing large amount of data. (`VACUUM FULL` is mainly useful for the OS to reclaim disk space, and you'd still need to analyse afterwards, especially after rebuilding indexes.)

It seems from your query that your main table is `SalesDataInvoiced` (`SDI`) and that you'd want to use an index on `KeyBillingMonth` if possible (since it's the main restriction you're placing). In general, you'd also want indexes, at least on the other tables on the columns that are used for the joins.

As the documentation for [multi-column indexes in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/indexes-multicolumn.html) says:

> A multicolumn B-tree index can be used with query conditions that involve any subset of the index's columns, but the index is most efficient when there are constraints on the leading (leftmost) columns. The exact rule is that equality constraints on leading columns, plus any inequality constraints on the first column that does not have an equality constraint, will be used to limit the portion of the index that is scanned. Constraints on columns to the right of these columns are checked in the index, so they save visits to the table proper, but they do not reduce the portion of the index that has to be scanned. For example, given an index on (a, b, c) and a query condition WHERE a = 5 AND b >= 42 AND c < 77, the index would have to be scanned from the first entry with a = 5 and b = 42 up through the last entry with a = 5. Index entries with c >= 77 would be skipped, but they'd still have to be scanned through. **This index could in principle be used for queries that have constraints on b and/or c with no constraint on a — but the entire index would have to be scanned, so in most cases the planner would prefer a sequential table scan over using the index.**

In your example, the main column you'd want to use a constraint on (`KeyBillingMonth`) is in third position, so it's unlikely to be used.

```sql
CREATE INDEX CI_SalesData ON public.SalesDataInvoiced
   USING btree (KeyShipTo, KeyProductCode, KeyBillingMonth)
```

Creating this should make it more likely to be used:

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON SalesDataInvoiced(KeyBillingMonth);
```

Then, run `VACUUM ANALYZE` and try your query again.

You may also want an index on `BillingMonth(ActualDate)`, but that's not necessarily useful since there seems to be few rows (and most of them are returned in your query).

It's not clear what the `BillingMonth` table is for. If it's basically about truncating the `ActualDate` to have the first day of the month, you could for example get rid of the join on `BillingMonth` and use the constraint on `SalesDataInvoiced.KeyBillingMonth` directly. For example `... WHERE SDI.KeyBillingMonth BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2021-10-01' ...`.

As a side-note, as far as I know, `BETWEEN` is inclusive for its upper bound. I'd imagine a query like this is meant to represent some monthly statistics, hence should probably not include what's on 2021-10-01 (but not the rest of that month).

Comment: Thanks Bruno, there are some good points for me to follow up on. My initial query is just one of many fired off from power BI when interacting with a dashboard. The BillingMonth table is a cut down version of my Dates table, holding information such as number of working days in a month etc. The primary key for the table is KeyDate which is an integer value. ActualDate is held as a date and used for date calculation within power BI.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I have tried the indexing suggested for both the BillingMonth table (adding ActualDate as an index) and SalesData_Invoiced table (Firstly tried indexing only on BillingMonth then creating a non clustered index in following order KeyBillingMonth, KeyProductCode, KeyShipTo). Unfortunately non of these changes improved the speed of the query. VACUUM ANALYZE was run after a Reindex for every change made. If you have any other ideas I'm more than willing to give them a try :)

Comment: You seem to be talking of "clustered / non-clustered" indexes. AFAIK, that doesn't have the same meaning in SQL Server and PostgreSQL. (In PostgreSQL, the main index doesn't determine the page location of the data.) I'm not sure whether you've actually used "CLUSTERED", but I'd avoid at first. I'd try to simplify the query, firstly by getting rid of the CROSS JOIN (which is useless), and adding perhaps one join at a time to see when indexes are used and not. Perhaps try with given known values of KeyBillingMonth (maybe just one or a "IN" condition) to see if it changes the behaviour.